# Javascript, Faker, Export module

Tags: javascript, export, faker

I am new to JS. This problem comes from one of my assignment with Thinkful. I have to use the faker package and then export to module as a function. Whenever I run the code, I got an error message that there isn't a object for faker. Can anyone help?

```js
let faker = require("faker");

function plantGenerator() {
    return {
        name: faker.name.findName(),
        color: faker.commerce.color(),
    };
}
module.export = plantGenerator;
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `module.export`, change `export` to `exports`. It works for me.